# Python - Combobox, not selecting value

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm wrinting a simple GUI app in PyCharm.
I'm using a combobox for selecting a value and a button to activate a action after choosing this value. I don't know how to show a message if a default value (that is this case nothing) is selected and the button is clicked.

Thanks for the help :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import shutil

root = Tk()
root.geometry("538x400")

def copyButton():

   msc = myCommbo.get() 
   if (# I don't know what): 
      messagebox.showinfo("Value not selected") 
   else:
      # do something

myCommbo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=["15","16","17","18","19","20"])
myCommbo.current()

myButton1 = Button(root, text="Copy to Archive", command=copyButton)

myCommbo.grid(row=2, column=1)
myButton1.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=50, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `msc` will be a string, so a simple `if not msc:` will do the job

Comment: Yes it did, thanks for the help I didn't thougt about this :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment:

> msc will be a string, so a simple if not msc: will do the job

Or a test for a specific value `if msc == "":`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import shutil

root = Tk()
root.geometry("538x400")

def copyButton():

    msc = myCommbo.get() 
    if not msc:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Value not selected") 
        return
    # Copy file to archive here 
    # Test copy result: if successful
    messagebox.showinfo("File Archive", "File Archived")
    # else
    # messagebox.showinfo("File Archive", "Archive Failed")

myCommbo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=["15","16","17","18","19","20"])
myCommbo.current()

myButton1 = Button(root, text="Copy to Archive", command=copyButton)

myCommbo.grid(row=2, column=1)
myButton1.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=50, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```